# Query to find second largest value from every group

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have three tables:

1. `project: project_id, project_name`
2. `milestone: milestone_id, milestone_name`
3. `project_milestone: id, project_id, milestone_id, completed_date`

I want to get the second highest completed_date and milestone_id from project_milestone grouped by project_id. That is I want to get the milestone_id of second highest completed_date for each project. What would be the correct query for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with the `project_milestone` table and `row_number()`:

```
select pm.*
from (select pm.*,
             row_number() over (partition by project_id order by completed_date desc) as seqnum
      from project_milestone pm
      where pm.completed_date is not null
     ) pm
where seqnum = 2;
```

If you need to include *all* projects, even those without two milestones, you can use a `left join`:

```
select p.project_id, pm.milestone_id, pm.completed_date
from projects p left join
     (select pm.*,
             row_number() over (partition by project_id order by completed_date desc) as seqnum
      from project_milestone pm
      where pm.completed_date is not null
     ) pm
     on p.project_id = pm.project_id and pm.seqnum = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks.It is working, but when there is null value in the completed_date it is coming above date values and the order gets changed. Is it possible to avoid null values

Comment: ok. I solved it by adding the condition "where pm.completed_date is not null" in the sub query

Answer (score 0):

Using LATERAL (PG 9.3+) can yield better performance than the window function version.

```
SELECT * FROM project;
 project_id | project_name 
------------+--------------
          1 | Project A
          2 | Project B

SELECT * FROM project_milestone;
 id | project_id | milestone_id |     completed_date     
----+------------+--------------+------------------------
  1 |          1 |            1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00+01
  2 |          1 |            2 | 2000-01-02 00:00:00+01
  3 |          1 |            5 | 2000-01-03 00:00:00+01
  4 |          1 |            6 | 2000-01-04 00:00:00+01
  5 |          2 |            3 | 2000-02-01 00:00:00+01
  6 |          2 |            4 | 2000-02-02 00:00:00+01
  7 |          2 |            7 | 2000-02-03 00:00:00+01
  8 |          2 |            8 | 2000-02-04 00:00:00+01


SELECT *
FROM project p
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT milestone_id, completed_date
    FROM project_milestone pm
    WHERE pm.project_id = p.project_id
    ORDER BY completed_date ASC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 1
) second_highest;
 project_id | project_name | milestone_id |     completed_date     
------------+--------------+--------------+------------------------
          1 | Project A    |            2 | 2000-01-02 00:00:00+01
          2 | Project B    |            4 | 2000-02-02 00:00:00+01
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use the window function.

```
SELECT *, nth_value(completed_date,2)
OVER (
    PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY completed_date DESC
    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
)
AS date2
FROM project_milestone;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using common table expression (CTE).

```
WITH cte_data AS(
   SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY completed_date DESC) 
   AS date_rank
   FROM project_milestone
   WHERE completed_date is not null
   )
SELECT * FROM cte_data
where date_rank = 2;
```